# Delete multiple canvas

Tags: javascript

I need to delete multiple canvas elements created. With the function below I can delete one every time I click a button but I need to delete all canvas created at once. How can I do this?

```
function deleteCanvas() {
  var list = document.getElementById("output");
  list.removeChild(list.childNodes[0]);
}
```

Comment: can you post your html file?

Comment: are all of your canvas elements contained inside the "output" element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `while` and as long as there are child elements in the list, keep removing them:

```js
function deleteCanvas() {
  var list = document.getElementById("output");
  while(list.childNodes.length) {
    list.removeChild(list.childNodes[0]);
  }
}
```

```css
canvas {
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 outline: solid red 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="output">
  <canvas></canvas>
  <canvas></canvas>
  <canvas></canvas>
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>

<button onclick="deleteCanvas()">delete all canvas elements</button>
```

Comment: Note this will indiscriminately remove all nodes in the parent element and not check if it is removing a canvas element or not. Also `childNodes` includes text nodes so you might accidentally remove non-empty text nodes. `children` might be a better option as it only contains elements.

Answer (score 3):

[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), and the various [getElementsBy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) methods can select multiple elements. Just loop over the returned list and remove() as nessary

For instance if you have a bunch of `<canvas class="game">` elements that you want removed you can use the `canvas.game` css selector with querySelectorAll, or passing `game` to `getElementsByClassName` to target those specific elements (leaving other canvas elements alone):

```
let list = document.querySelectorAll('canvas.game');
//or
let list = document.getElementsByClassName("game");

for(let i=0; i<list.length; i++){
  list[i].remove();
}
```

Comment: @FZs they do: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove and there is a polyfill for older browsers (IE)

Comment: Oh yes, I see! I didn't know about it! I've always used `node.parentNode.removeChild(node)` for this... until now. +1

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this ?

```
let canvasses = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");
//you can also do this with classes.

while (canvasses.length > 0) {
    for (let i =0; i < canvasses.length; i++) {
        canvasses[i].remove();
    }
}
```